# Accessing local service running on Colab Notebook server

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using Google Colab Notebook, and there is a service started by my code running on http://localhost:8787. How I can access it from my browser? I came across Jupyter Server Proxy which might help, but I don't know how.